# How to create successive modal windows using ngDialog

Tags: angularjs

Suppose in a screen I click on a button a new modal window should be opened. This modal window should be followed by successive modal windows on button click. I was reading about [ngdialog](http://likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/#). I even saw their sample example.But did not get clarity on how to do it.

Comment: Are you trying to create some kind of wizard interface? If so, you could just open a single modal window and then use a angular-wizard to go through the various steps and then close the modal window on the last step.

Comment: I'm trying to do as it is done in ngDialog sample when you click on demo button.

Answer (score 0):

From the code below, you can see that when the user clicks the 'demo' button, `MainCtrl.open()` is executed which opens the first dialog managed by the controller `FirstDialogCtrl`.

Then once the `FirstDialogCtrl.next()` function is executed, the first dialog is closed via the call `ngDialog.close('ngdialog1');`, and the next dialog opened in the chain.

```
var app = angular.module('exampleDialog', ['ngDialog']);

            app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, ngDialog) {
                $scope.open = function () {
                    ngDialog.open({
                        template: 'firstDialog',
                        controller: 'FirstDialogCtrl',
                        className: 'ngdialog-theme-default ngdialog-theme-custom'
                    });
                };
            });

            app.controller('FirstDialogCtrl', function ($scope, ngDialog) {
                $scope.next = function () {
                    ngDialog.close('ngdialog1');
                    ngDialog.open({
                        template: 'secondDialog',
                        className: 'ngdialog-theme-flat ngdialog-theme-custom'
                    });
                };
            });
```